# Can I make up my own html5 input types?

Tags: html

The new HTML5 input types and attributes, ie `tel`, `email`, `pattern`, etc are useful for indicating to an unobtrusive javascript validator what rules should be applied to a given field.

In some cases though, a specific field type which isn't in the spec needs a special algorithm. For example, `input type="credit-card"` would cause the validator to use a modulo10 algorithm, which pattern matching can't validate.

The new input types work because old browsers fall-back to `type="text"` when it doesn't understand the type specified. From what I can tell, new browsers seem to follow this convention as well.

Since there is already a `type` attribute which is semantically correct, it seems messy and inconsistent to use a separate `data-type=""` attribute some of the time and the official `type` attribute when the needed type already exists.

I understand that some day there could be a type with the same name, but if the W3C adds an `input type="credit-card"` at some point in the future, what are the odds it would do something other than validate a credit card? (Or in other words, so long as the types are named well, the only conflict would be what was intended anyway).

Are there any pitfalls to simply making up new input types as I need them?

Comment: Just like you have correctly observed, those types might be populated in the future. On top of that, everyone who picks up the code after you is going to be super-confused reading non-existent field types. Just stick to data atrributes or class names.

Comment: I don't think a developer who is "super-confused" by `<input type="credit-card" />` is someone I would want working on one of my projects! To clarify, I'm not looking for a philosophical answer on if it *should* be done, but rather a technical answer on "will it work as intended on all major browsers today".

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a javascript framework, especially if you're starting a new project.  In these frameworks you can create reusable components.  For example, you can define a credit card component, implement your specific validation and styles and logic, and then reuse your new component throughout your application.

In angular.js, the most popular javascript framework which is backed by Google, it's called a directive:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

In ember.js, it's called a component.

Pitfalls for the credit card example would be trying to invent your own regular expressions for validation or finding a bad regex online that doesn't actually work.  But use of custom web components in javascript frameworks is pretty standard.  You should also make sure that whatever fancy javascript libraries you use are compatible with whatever browsers and browser configurations you want to support.